# Merge on same column in R

Tags: r, merge

My colleague and I are collecting data on separate files and we want to reconcile the data. Our data files look like so:

```
df1 = data.frame(Id = c(1:5), Score= c(10,NA,4,NA,3))
df2 = data.frame(UserID= c(1:5), Result= c(NA,8,NA,3,NA))
```

What is the simplest way to merge the two to form the following dataset to attain the following result?

```
df3 = data.frame(Id= c(1:5), Score= c(10,8,4,3,3))
```

Changing column names and using merge() don't seem to work which is what I had hoped.

Any suggestions? Would the quickest to be run a for loop across both datasets?

Comment: What about `coalesce`? Does this help: `df1$Score <- dplyr::coalesce(df1$Score, df2$Result)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for the function `coalesce` in the library `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::coalesce(df1,df2)
  Id Score
1  1    10
2  2     8
3  3     4
4  4     3
5  5     3
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr)


inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Id" = "UserID")) %>%  #specify the column names to join
  mutate(Score = ifelse (is.na(Score), Result, Score)) %>% #This will fill all the NA Scores with values of Result
  select(Id, Score) #Finally, Select the two columns you desire
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that any NA in one df corresponds to a value in the other df, the simplest solution is by using an `ifelse()` statement to insert the values from df2 inlieu of the NA in df1, thus:

```
df1$Score <- ifelse(is.na(df1$Score), df2$Result, df1$Score)
```

This says: if `df1$Score` is NA, write the value of `df2$Result`, otherwise keep `df1$Score`

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` this should work as well:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("Id", "Score"), by.y = c("UserID", "Result"), all = T)
df3 <- df3[!is.na(df3$Score),]
df3
```